Streaming file from one webserver to another
I'm trying to stream a file from one webserver (Jfrog) to another (nexus content server).
I have working code that does this like this:
def get_file():
    url = "https://webserver.com/big_file.zip"
    with requests.get(url,, stream=True) as file_stream:
        self.stream_file_to_webserver(file_stream)

def stream_file_to_webserver(file_stream):
    upload_url = "https://nexus.com/big_file.zip"
    with requests.put(upload_url, data=file_stream.iter_content(chunk_size=8192), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}) as response:
        if response.status_code != 201:
            print("Success")


This works fine, but I need to upload to the Nexus content server in a different (because of another issue with other metadata fields missing when you upload this way).
There I want to upload this way:
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

class FileWrapper:
    def __init__(self, file_iterator):
        self.file_iterator = file_iterator

    def read(self, size=-1):
        return next(self.file_iterator, b'')

    def get_file():
        url = "https://webserver.com/big_file.zip"
        with requests.get(url,, stream=True) as file_stream:
            self.stream_file_to_webserver(file_stream)

    def stream_file_to_webserver(source_response):
        upload_url = f"https://nexus.com/repository"
        
        file_wrapper = FileWrapper(source_response.iter_content(chunk_size=8192))
        
        payload = {
            'raw.directory': ('/'),
            'raw.asset1.filename': ('big_file.zip'),
            'raw.asset1': ('big_file.zip', file_wrapper)
        }

        with requests.post(upload_url, files=payload) as response:
            if response.status_code == 201:
                print("File uploaded to Nexus successfully.")
            else:
                print(f"Failed {response.text}")

But this seems to fail because somehow the payload is not set correctly.
 [{"id":"directory","message":"Missing required component field 'Directory'"},{"id":"filename","message":"Missing required asset field 'Filename' on '1'"},{"id":"filename","message":"Missing required asset field 'Filename' on '2'"},{"id":"filename","message":"Missing required asset field 'Filename' on '3'"},{"id":"*","message":"The assets 1 and 2 have identical coordinates"},{"id":"*","message":"The assets 2 and 3 have identical coordinates"}]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this?

It looks like your second server uses a different format for passing in the metadata.

The problem is in your call.
{"id":"filename","message":"Missing required asset field 'Filename' on '1'"}

This is because the syntax of an asset object has 3 parameters:  (filename, file, content_type), but you only passed two.
'raw.asset1': ('big_file.zip', file_wrapper, 'application/zip')

Would be the correct  call.
Now, this error
{"id":"directory","message":"Missing required component field 'Directory'"}

Happens because the syntax of a non-file object has 2 parameters (None, value), but you only passed one.
'raw.directory': (None, '/'),
'raw.asset1.filename': (None, 'big_file.zip'),

Non-files are indicated by the None parameter. In the case of raw.directory, the expected syntax was (None, Directory), that's why you're getting the error.
Finally, this one:
{"id":"*","message":"The assets 1 and 2 have identical coordinates"}

Indicates that you're trying to use the same path for multiple files, that is, you're sending the same file multiple times.

Thank you - Now it uploads the file but the size of the uploaded file is 8KB. So it seems to only upload the first chunk_size=8192 and not the rest of the file. Do you know how I can solve this?

That's because you're only reading the first chunk of the file. The requests lib expects that your read method is able to be called multiple times, so you need to make it so that happens, which currently isn't the case

I posted a possible fix on a separate answer


Thank you - Now it uploads the file but the size of the uploaded file is 8KB. So it seems to only upload the first chunk_size=8192 and not the rest of the file. Do you know how I can solve this?

As i said on a comment, this happens because your read method only reads one chunk of your file
Here's an example of a fix (a method that will read the entire file)
It didn't fit in a comment, so i'm creating another answer
def __init__(self, file_iterator):
        self.file_iterator = file_iterator
        self.buffer = b''

def read(self, size=-1):
        if size == -1:
            return b''.join(self.file_iterator)
        else:
            while len(self.buffer) < size:
                try:
                    self.buffer += next(self.file_iterator)
                except StopIteration:
                    break
            result, self.buffer = self.buffer[:size], self.buffer[size:]
            return result


But this reads the whole file into memory right? The file is 10GB so that will be a problem. Thats why I thought streaming the file chunk by chunk would be a better option.


But this reads the whole file into memory right? The file is 10GB so
that will be a problem. Thats why I thought streaming the file chunk
by chunk would be a better option.

I'll have to create a separate answer again to answer that because of the character limit in comments.
Well, in this case, reading it chunk by chunk is the way to go, the implementation that uses buffers is kind of inefficient, specially for such large files.
Here's one of the possible solutions using a streaming approach, which reads the file chunk by chunk and doesn't render them into memory.
class FileWrapper:
def __init__(self, file_iterator):
    self.file_iterator = file_iterator
    self.exhausted = False

def read(self, size=-1):
    if self.exhausted:
        return b''
    try:
        return next(self.file_iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        self.exhausted = True
        return b''


The same issue is still happening with the first 8KB being uploaded but not the rest
